# How to delegate a subdomain (and its sub-subdomains) to another nameserver?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, delegation

We are using our own DNS server in out local network, which works fine. Domains need to be accessible only from within the local network. Let's say the domain name is *ourdomain.com*.

Now we've created a subdomain *public.ourdomain.com*, and we want all sub-subdomains of it to be public. For example, *test.public.ourdomain.co*m, *experiment.public.ourdomain.com*, *demo.public.ourdomain.com* are created and hosted at an external webhosting provider.

These domains can now be accessed from the public internet, but in our local network, the problem is that our local DNS is queried and it doesn't know about those external domains.

Now how can I make our local DNS delegate to the external DNS, so I don't have to copy all the external entries locally?

I googled for instructions and came up with a separate zone file for *public.ourdomain.com* that has NS entries pointing to the external DNS:

```
public.ourdomain.com.             10800 IN SOA  public.ourdomain.com. admin.public.ourdomain.com. 
                      10800 IN NS   ns1.external-hoster.de.
```

But I seem to be missing something, because I get neither *public.ourdomain.com* nor *test.public.ourdomain.com* resolved from within our local network.

```
 *** Can't find public.ourdomain.com: No answer
```

According to the instructions I found, I would need to update the parent zone file (for *ourdomain.com*) by adding a delegation for the subdomain? How? I cannot find an example.

How to make the local DNS server properly delegate for *public.ourdomain.com* and its sub-subdomains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have configured your local DNS to be authoritative for `example.com` and not only for `internal.example.com` (because then you wouldn't have this problem) ;

you add `NS` records for `public.example.com` in your internal DNS with the name servers for your external / public DNS (and not a SOA record) :

```
public.example.com. IN NS  ns1.provider.example.net.
public.example.com. IN NS  ns2.provider.example.net.
```

That delegates public.example.com. and all possible records below that to the name servers operated by your provider.

Comment: Thanks. First, I got `SERVFAIL` back, but then I figured that I should not have a _public.ourdomain.com_ zone file, but add the lines to the _ourdomain.com_ zone file (and remove the _public.ourdomain.com_ zone file), and then it worked!

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, can you add an explanation why the `SOA` entry was not right here?

Comment: The Start Of Authority record designates the start of a zone. - The NS record designates that a zone (starting from public.example.com in this example)  should be found at the designated hosts ns1 and ns2.provider.example.net.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types